# /snap/bin cutoff my /etc/environment path variable settings

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 and currently keeping my path variable settings in /etc/environment settings, it was all fine until my path setting reaches a specific length, /snap/bin would just cutoff in my $PATH variable, causing the necessary to source the /etc/environment everytime when I log in again...

This is my /etc/environment path

```
echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/opt/vcftools_0.1.13/bin
/opt/PLINK_v1.90b6.5
/opt/FastQC
/opt/GATK-4.0.6
/opt/samtools-1.9/bin
/opt/samtools-1.9/htslib-1.9
/opt/bcftools-1.9/bin
/opt/bedtools2/bin
/opt/cmake-3.12.3/bin
/opt/bamtools-final/usr/local/bin
/opt/hmmer-3.2.1-final/bin
/opt/Augustus/bin
/opt/Augustus/scripts
/opt/R-3.5.1-final/bin
/opt/busco/scripts
/opt/Platanus_v1.2.4
/opt/jemalloc-final/bin
/opt/discovardenovo-52488-final/bin
/opt/quast-5.0.1
/opt/gffread-0.9.12
/opt/hisat2-2.1.0
/opt/GapCloser-v1.12-r6/bin
/opt/SOAPdenovo2-bin-LINUX-generic-r240
/opt/trf-4.09
/opt/rmblast-2.6.0/bin
/opt/RECON-1.08/bin
/opt/RepeatScout-1.0.5
/opt/RepeatMasker
/opt/RepeatModeler-open-1.0.11
/opt/satsuma-code-0
/opt/minimap2
/opt/twoBitToFa-20181128
/opt/gt-1.5.10-Linux_x86_64-64bit-complete/bin
/opt/supernova-2.1.1
/opt/gm_et_linux_64/gmes_petap
/opt/gth-1.7.1-Linux_x86_64-64bit/bin
/opt/exonerate-2.4.0/bin
/opt/BRAKER/scripts
/opt/bcl2fastq-final/bin
/opt/longranger-2.2.2/longranger-cs/2.2.2/bin
/opt/TransDecoder-TransDecoder-v5.5.0
/opt/blast-2.2.26/bin
/opt/kraken2
/opt/inparanoid_4.1
/home/cch/.local/bin
```

Like, up until bcl2fastq's pathway /snap/bin would attach correctly after the whole path variable stream (I tried to delete the string to make it shorter), but expansion upon that /snap/bin would just cut off the string in the middle:

```
cch@ubuntu16:~$ echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'
/home/cch/bin
/home/cch/.local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/opt/vcftools_0.1.13/bin
/opt/PLINK_v1.90b6.5
/opt/FastQC
/opt/GATK-4.0.6
/opt/samtools-1.9/bin
/opt/samtools-1.9/htslib-1.9
/opt/bcftools-1.9/bin
/opt/bedtools2/bin
/opt/cmake-3.12.3/bin
/opt/bamtools-final/usr/local/bin
/opt/hmmer-3.2.1-final/bin
/opt/Augustus/bin
/opt/Augustus/scripts
/opt/R-3.5.1-final/bin
/opt/busco/scripts
/opt/Platanus_v1.2.4
/opt/jemalloc-final/bin
/opt/discovardenovo-52488-final/bin
/opt/quast-5.0.1
/opt/gffread-0.9.12
/opt/hisat2-2.1.0
/opt/GapCloser-v1.12-r6/bin
/opt/SOAPdenovo2-bin-LINUX-generic-r240
/opt/trf-4.09
/opt/rmblast-2.6.0/bin
/opt/RECON-1.08/bin
/opt/RepeatScout-1.0.5
/opt/RepeatMasker
/opt/RepeatModeler-open-1.0.11
/opt/satsuma-code-0
/opt/minimap2
/opt/twoBitToFa-20181128
/opt/gt-1.5.10-Linux_x86_64-64bit-complete/bin
/opt/supernova-2.1.1
/opt/gm_et_linux_64/gmes_petap
/opt/gth-1.7.1-Linux_x86_64-64bit/bin
/opt/exonerate-2.4.0/bin
/opt/BRAKER/scripts
/opt/bcl2fastq-final/b
/snap/bin
```

This is my /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh which apparently has the code bits that append the /snap/bin to your path, but I'm not sure whether if I should alter it because it seems to be important

```
# shellcheck shell=sh

# Expand $PATH to include the directory where snappy applications go.
snap_bin_path="/snap/bin"
if [ -n "${PATH##*${snap_bin_path}}" -a -n "${PATH##*${snap_bin_path}:*}" ]; then
    export PATH=$PATH:${snap_bin_path}
fi

# Ensure base distro defaults xdg path are set if nothing filed up some
# defaults yet.
if [ -z "$XDG_DATA_DIRS" ]; then
    export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/local/share:/usr/share"
fi

# Desktop files (used by desktop environments within both X11 and Wayland) are
# looked for in XDG_DATA_DIRS; make sure it includes the relevant directory for
# snappy applications' desktop files.
snap_xdg_path="/var/lib/snapd/desktop"
if [ -n "${XDG_DATA_DIRS##*${snap_xdg_path}}" -a -n "${XDG_DATA_DIRS##*${snap_xdg_path}:*}" ]; then
    export XDG_DATA_DIRS="${XDG_DATA_DIRS}:${snap_xdg_path}"
fi
```

This is my default setting from /etc/login.defs, but I think my /etc/environment also applies everytime I log in

```
# *REQUIRED*  The default PATH settings, for superuser and normal users.
#
# (they are minimal, add the rest in the shell startup files)
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Do anyone has any idea on this???

Thanks in advance for your help

I did echo -n "$PATH"|od -xc following the suggestiong from cdarke and tripleee

this is the output when I re-login and the $PATH is interrupted by /snap/bin

```
0000000    682f    6d6f    2f65    6363    2f68    6962    3a6e    682f
          /   h   o   m   e   /   c   c   h   /   b   i   n   :   /   h
0000020    6d6f    2f65    6363    2f68    6c2e    636f    6c61    622f
          o   m   e   /   c   c   h   /   .   l   o   c   a   l   /   b
0000040    6e69    2f3a    7375    2f72    6f6c    6163    2f6c    6273
          i   n   :   /   u   s   r   /   l   o   c   a   l   /   s   b
0000060    6e69    2f3a    7375    2f72    6f6c    6163    2f6c    6962
          i   n   :   /   u   s   r   /   l   o   c   a   l   /   b   i
0000100    3a6e    752f    7273    732f    6962    3a6e    752f    7273
          n   :   /   u   s   r   /   s   b   i   n   :   /   u   s   r
0000120    622f    6e69    2f3a    6273    6e69    2f3a    6962    3a6e
          /   b   i   n   :   /   s   b   i   n   :   /   b   i   n   :
0000140    752f    7273    672f    6d61    7365    2f3a    7375    2f72
          /   u   s   r   /   g   a   m   e   s   :   /   u   s   r   /
0000160    6f6c    6163    2f6c    6167    656d    3a73    6f2f    7470
          l   o   c   a   l   /   g   a   m   e   s   :   /   o   p   t
0000200    762f    6663    6f74    6c6f    5f73    2e30    2e31    3331
          /   v   c   f   t   o   o   l   s   _   0   .   1   .   1   3
0000220    622f    6e69    2f3a    706f    2f74    4c50    4e49    5f4b
          /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   P   L   I   N   K   _
0000240    3176    392e    6230    2e36    3a35    6f2f    7470    462f
          v   1   .   9   0   b   6   .   5   :   /   o   p   t   /   F
0000260    7361    5174    3a43    6f2f    7470    472f    5441    2d4b
          a   s   t   Q   C   :   /   o   p   t   /   G   A   T   K   -
0000300    2e34    2e30    3a36    6f2f    7470    732f    6d61    6f74
          4   .   0   .   6   :   /   o   p   t   /   s   a   m   t   o
0000320    6c6f    2d73    2e31    2f39    6962    3a6e    6f2f    7470
          o   l   s   -   1   .   9   /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t
0000340    732f    6d61    6f74    6c6f    2d73    2e31    2f39    7468
          /   s   a   m   t   o   o   l   s   -   1   .   9   /   h   t
0000360    6c73    6269    312d    392e    2f3a    706f    2f74    6362
          s   l   i   b   -   1   .   9   :   /   o   p   t   /   b   c
0000400    7466    6f6f    736c    312d    392e    622f    6e69    2f3a
          f   t   o   o   l   s   -   1   .   9   /   b   i   n   :   /
0000420    706f    2f74    6562    7464    6f6f    736c    2f32    6962
          o   p   t   /   b   e   d   t   o   o   l   s   2   /   b   i
0000440    3a6e    6f2f    7470    632f    616d    656b    332d    312e
          n   :   /   o   p   t   /   c   m   a   k   e   -   3   .   1
0000460    2e32    2f33    6962    3a6e    6f2f    7470    622f    6d61
          2   .   3   /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   b   a   m
0000500    6f74    6c6f    2d73    6966    616e    2f6c    7375    2f72
          t   o   o   l   s   -   f   i   n   a   l   /   u   s   r   /
0000520    6f6c    6163    2f6c    6962    3a6e    6f2f    7470    682f
          l   o   c   a   l   /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   h
0000540    6d6d    7265    332d    322e    312e    662d    6e69    6c61
          m   m   e   r   -   3   .   2   .   1   -   f   i   n   a   l
0000560    622f    6e69    2f3a    706f    2f74    7541    7567    7473
          /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   A   u   g   u   s   t
0000600    7375    622f    6e69    2f3a    706f    2f74    7541    7567
          u   s   /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   A   u   g   u
0000620    7473    7375    732f    7263    7069    7374    2f3a    706f
          s   t   u   s   /   s   c   r   i   p   t   s   :   /   o   p
0000640    2f74    2d52    2e33    2e35    2d31    6966    616e    2f6c
          t   /   R   -   3   .   5   .   1   -   f   i   n   a   l   /
0000660    6962    3a6e    6f2f    7470    622f    7375    6f63    732f
          b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   b   u   s   c   o   /   s
0000700    7263    7069    7374    2f3a    706f    2f74    6c50    7461
          c   r   i   p   t   s   :   /   o   p   t   /   P   l   a   t
0000720    6e61    7375    765f    2e31    2e32    3a34    6f2f    7470
          a   n   u   s   _   v   1   .   2   .   4   :   /   o   p   t
0000740    6a2f    6d65    6c61    6f6c    2d63    6966    616e    2f6c
          /   j   e   m   a   l   l   o   c   -   f   i   n   a   l   /
0000760    6962    3a6e    6f2f    7470    642f    7369    6f63    6176
          b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   d   i   s   c   o   v   a
0001000    6472    6e65    766f    2d6f    3235    3834    2d38    6966
          r   d   e   n   o   v   o   -   5   2   4   8   8   -   f   i
0001020    616e    2f6c    6962    3a6e    6f2f    7470    712f    6175
          n   a   l   /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   q   u   a
0001040    7473    352d    302e    312e    2f3a    706f    2f74    6667
          s   t   -   5   .   0   .   1   :   /   o   p   t   /   g   f
0001060    7266    6165    2d64    2e30    2e39    3231    2f3a    706f
          f   r   e   a   d   -   0   .   9   .   1   2   :   /   o   p
0001100    2f74    6968    6173    3274    322d    312e    302e    2f3a
          t   /   h   i   s   a   t   2   -   2   .   1   .   0   :   /
0001120    706f    2f74    6147    4370    6f6c    6573    2d72    3176
          o   p   t   /   G   a   p   C   l   o   s   e   r   -   v   1
0001140    312e    2d32    3672    622f    6e69    3a2f    6f2f    7470
          .   1   2   -   r   6   /   b   i   n   /   :   /   o   p   t
0001160    532f    414f    6450    6e65    766f    326f    622d    6e69
          /   S   O   A   P   d   e   n   o   v   o   2   -   b   i   n
0001200    4c2d    4e49    5855    672d    6e65    7265    6369    722d
          -   L   I   N   U   X   -   g   e   n   e   r   i   c   -   r
0001220    3432    3a30    6f2f    7470    742f    6672    342d    302e
          2   4   0   :   /   o   p   t   /   t   r   f   -   4   .   0
0001240    3a39    6f2f    7470    722f    626d    616c    7473    322d
          9   :   /   o   p   t   /   r   m   b   l   a   s   t   -   2
0001260    362e    302e    622f    6e69    2f3a    706f    2f74    4552
          .   6   .   0   /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   R   E
0001300    4f43    2d4e    2e31    3830    622f    6e69    2f3a    706f
          C   O   N   -   1   .   0   8   /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p
0001320    2f74    6552    6570    7461    6353    756f    2d74    2e31
          t   /   R   e   p   e   a   t   S   c   o   u   t   -   1   .
0001340    2e30    3a35    6f2f    7470    522f    7065    6165    4d74
          0   .   5   :   /   o   p   t   /   R   e   p   e   a   t   M
0001360    7361    656b    3a72    6f2f    7470    522f    7065    6165
          a   s   k   e   r   :   /   o   p   t   /   R   e   p   e   a
0001400    4d74    646f    6c65    7265    6f2d    6570    2d6e    2e31
          t   M   o   d   e   l   e   r   -   o   p   e   n   -   1   .
0001420    2e30    3131    2f3a    706f    2f74    6173    7374    6d75
          0   .   1   1   :   /   o   p   t   /   s   a   t   s   u   m
0001440    2d61    6f63    6564    302d    2f3a    706f    2f74    696d
          a   -   c   o   d   e   -   0   :   /   o   p   t   /   m   i
0001460    696e    616d    3270    2f3a    706f    2f74    7774    426f
          n   i   m   a   p   2   :   /   o   p   t   /   t   w   o   B
0001500    7469    6f54    6146    322d    3130    3138    3231    3a38
          i   t   T   o   F   a   -   2   0   1   8   1   1   2   8   :
0001520    6f2f    7470    672f    2d74    2e31    2e35    3031    4c2d
          /   o   p   t   /   g   t   -   1   .   5   .   1   0   -   L
0001540    6e69    7875    785f    3638    365f    2d34    3436    6962
          i   n   u   x   _   x   8   6   _   6   4   -   6   4   b   i
0001560    2d74    6f63    706d    656c    6574    622f    6e69    2f3a
          t   -   c   o   m   p   l   e   t   e   /   b   i   n   :   /
0001600    706f    2f74    7573    6570    6e72    766f    2d61    2e32
          o   p   t   /   s   u   p   e   r   n   o   v   a   -   2   .
0001620    2e31    3a31    6f2f    7470    672f    5f6d    7465    6c5f
          1   .   1   :   /   o   p   t   /   g   m   _   e   t   _   l
0001640    6e69    7875    365f    2f34    6d67    7365    705f    7465
          i   n   u   x   _   6   4   /   g   m   e   s   _   p   e   t
0001660    7061    2f3a    706f    2f74    7467    2d68    2e31    2e37
          a   p   :   /   o   p   t   /   g   t   h   -   1   .   7   .
0001700    2d31    694c    756e    5f78    3878    5f36    3436    362d
          1   -   L   i   n   u   x   _   x   8   6   _   6   4   -   6
0001720    6234    7469    622f    6e69    2f3a    706f    2f74    7865
          4   b   i   t   /   b   i   n   :   /   o   p   t   /   e   x
0001740    6e6f    7265    7461    2d65    2e32    2e34    2f30    6962
          o   n   e   r   a   t   e   -   2   .   4   .   0   /   b   i
0001760    3a6e    6f2f    7470    422f    4152    454b    2f52    6373
          n   :   /   o   p   t   /   B   R   A   K   E   R   /   s   c
0002000    6972    7470    3a73    6f2f    7470    622f    6c63    6632
          r   i   p   t   s   :   /   o   p   t   /   b   c   l   2   f
0002020    7361    7174    662d    6e69    6c61    622f    2f3a    6e73
          a   s   t   q   -   f   i   n   a   l   /   b   :   /   s   n
0002040    7061    622f    6e69
          a   p   /   b   i   n
0002046
```

and I think it's the same for the original /etc/environment file

Comment: Are you perhaps using a copy/paste action to add the path?  It sounds like you have a rogue whitespace character, like `\r`, in your path.  To check, `echo -n $PATH|od -xc`.

Comment: I think some of the path I did use copy/paste to add instead of typing in, but I did the echo -n $PATH|od -xc to both the original /etc/environment and the $PATH when re-login, I don't see any \ backslashes inside..

Comment: `echo -n $PATH` without quotes will lose information; you want `echo -n "$PATH"` to preserve any whitespace etc.  But it's pretty clear that you have a a Windows carriage return in there.

Comment: ... Actually, on closer inspection, I don't think you have posted all the code which modifies your `PATH`. I'm guessing something earlier on on in your dotfiles truncates the string.  Where is the code which adds `/home/cch/bin:/home/cch/.local/bin:` to the front of your `PATH`?

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to read; could you present the `PATH` as something which isn't a single long line for improved legibility? Something like `echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'` maybe.

Comment: hello tripleee, sorry for the late reply, I have re-post the command line, my /etc/environment is exactly the same as shown above, and I wonder as well where do "/home/cch/bin:/home/cch/.local/bin:" this line come from(I checked my .bashrc file, it has nothing related...I tried to grep sudo grep -r $HOME/.local * or grep -r $HOME *, only this came out and I think it's irrelevant:
passwd:cch:x:1013:1013:,,,:/home/cch:/bin/bash
passwd-:cch:x:1013:1013:,,,:/home/cch:/bin/bash

do you have any idea where does it come from?